# How to handle two similar projects under /var/www/html and user login issue?

Tags: php

I find it difficult to express myself in one-sentence question. However anyway, hopefully following describes what I want to ask.

I need develop a website that will be used by two groups, say 
group1 and group2.

Two groups have the same structure and the same user types. For example, 

group1 has super-user-a (username aaa password aaa11), general-user-b/c/d 
group2 has super-user-a (username aaa password aaa22), general-user-e/f/g

Yes, they look like copy of each other. The reason both super-user-a have username aaa is because my php code will need check this, and I want it be static so that I can it's easier to handle. (Maybe having the same username is wrong at the beginning and should've avoided this ...)

and correspondently, in /var/www/html/ I have two projects

/var/www/html/project1 designed for group1

/var/www/html/project2 designed for group2

both /project1/ and /project2/ have all the same structure and PHP file, except database connect to db1 and db2, respectively for project1 and project2.

Here is the problem I have. 
superuser aaa of project1 login with password aaa11 at

mydomain.com/project1/login.php which check if db1 has aaa/aaa11 username/password pair. After login, superuser aaa can do things what he is supposed to do like view all secrets at 

mydomain.com/project1/secret.php.

Same thing for superuser aaa of project2, login with password aaa22 at 
mydomain.com/project2/login.php which check if db2 has aaa/aaa22 username/password pair, After login, he can view project2 secrets at

mydomain.com/project2/secret.php.

However, if aaa of project1 does not log out, and change URL at the web address bar from 

mydomain.com/project1/secret.php to 

mydomain.com/project2/secret.php
then aaa of project1 can view project2 secret
That's wrong and problematic of course.

Not sure if my session.php code matters. But anyway, I pasted it below.

I also think if it's possible to make files in /var/www/html/project1/ only accessible to usernames in db1. I have no idea how to achieve this either ...

```
<?php
include('config.php'); // this file has DB connect constants
session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query ($db, "select user_id from users where username = '$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user_id = $row['user_id'];   
$login_username = $user_check;;

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
   header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

TIA!!!

Comment: i dont see why you need 2 file sets, if they are identical - would make maintenance much harder

Comment: project1 talks to database db1 and project2 to db2

Comment: The point is this can be done easily in the same code base. There is no reason to over complicate your code because you want to talk to two different databases. There are plenty of apps that talk to more than one database and do not use two copies of the code. If your usernames dont duplicate from one database to another then you can simply check both. If they do duplicate it might be a good idea to have two separate logins depending on what the user needs to do.

Comment: i have a single code base that uses over 1k datbases. (1 per client (special case)) all you need is the db to use in the session, and use that in the  querries